# Make replies to an email sent via Contact Form 7 go to four different emails

Tags: wordpress, email, contact-form-7

When a user fills up a contact form on my website an email is sent out to them.

I want any reply made to this sent email to be also forwarded to 4 different emails.

I've tried using the "Additional headers" field with the following settings but the email does not get sent.

```
Reply-to: [your-email],email1@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com,email3@gmail.com,email4@gmail.com
```

Is there a syntax error or should I doing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Reply-To** with a capital T ([source](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822#section-3.6.2))

```
Reply-To: [your-email],email1@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com,email3@gmail.com,email4@gmail.com
```